# Calling a shell script from flume agent

Tags: hadoop, data-transfer, flume

I want to invoke a shell script from flume agent machine .
Is it possible to call a shell script using flume ? if yes how can i do it ?

Comment: Do you want to use the script to generate data, or to process data received via an input channel?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Chris White's comment:

If you want to use the script as a source then use the Exec Source.

If you want to use it as an interceptor then you could write a custom interceptor. However, performance would be very poor as you would be starting a new process for each message (or perhaps batch). I would recommend a custom Java interceptor.